# Image format conversion to jpeg without sending to output or saving to a file (Java)

Tags: java, image, jpeg

I wrote my remote pc control application. Server sends screenshots capture by Robot class and additional thread listens to Client's input (ex: mouse click) and does the same on the server pc.

After some time I get heap overflow, probably should clean ObjectOutputStream with reset(), but first thing to go faster I should work out how to compress Image object. As far as I read, ImageIO should help me, but I don't want to save it to a file or send it to a stream, just want to have a converted Image object.
  Ofcourse, why wouldn't I want to send it to my ObjectOutputStream to listening clients with ImageIO.write(blablalb, blablal, myOutputStream). Thing is, I've tried, and getting with reading or other problems, no exceptions or errors, Client's Logger says that it got two pictures (which weren't displayed) and then stucks. While my way without compression works well in this aspect.

So, I need help how to convert it without saving or sending and keep it in Object (then send it via ObjectOutputStream), or maybe at least fix ImageIO usage problem. I would prefer first way (don't want to have a mess with byte counting code and so on). Thank you for help.

Here's some code, I've got a lot of classes and code, but hope this helps:
*Image (wrapped into ImageIcon) object sending way*

**Server side's Image sending related pieces**

```
public class BroadcastWorker implements Runnable {
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    //private BlockingQueue<Image> imagesBuffer;
    private boolean finnish = false;
    private long frequency = 50;
    private Screen screen = new Screen();

    public BroadcastWorker(Socket connection) throws IOException {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        //ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
        // outputui resetas atlaisvina vietos

    }

    /*
    public void addImage(Image image) {
        imagesBuffer.add(image);
    }
    * 
    */

    private void send(Image image) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sending image");
        output.writeObject(new ImageIcon(image));
        //ImageOutputStream imageOutput = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
        //ImageIO.write((RenderedImage)image, "jpeg", imageOutput);
        System.out.println("image sent");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!finnish) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(frequency);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BroadcastWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                send(screen.getScreenshot());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BroadcastWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**ClientGui class with part of code related to receiving and setting Image**

```
public class ClientGui1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Socket connection;
    private ScreenReceiveWorker receiver = new ScreenReceiveWorker();
    private ActionSendWorker actionSender = new ActionSendWorker();
    /**
    * 
    */
    class ScreenReceiveWorker extends SwingWorker {
        private Image progress;

        private void setScreen(Image progress) {
            this.progress = progress;
        }

        private Image getScreen() {
            return progress;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            //ImageInputStream imageInput = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);

            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                System.out.println("Screeeen");
                Image screen = ((ImageIcon) input.readObject()).getImage();
                //Image screen = ImageIO.read(imageInput);
                System.out.println("received");
                panelScreen.setImage(screen);
                panelScreen.repaint();

            }
        }
    }

......
.....
```

Comment: Write the `BufferedImage` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` from which you can call `getBytes()` to get the encoded image.  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) I doubt my point will fix the problem, since it is possible to do image compression direct to the stream the client is reading.  It would be better to do that, rather than pursue other strategies that will lead to the same problems in the long run.